# PFRelation addObject does not add relation

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfobject, pfrelation

I'm trying to add an object to a relation in Parse, although the code gets exectued without any errors the relation does not appear in the backend, therefore the object was not saved.

```
PFObject *newContact = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Contact"];

[newContact saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Trip"];
    PFObject *trip = [query getObjectWithId:self.parseID];

    PFRelation *rel = [trip relationForKey:@"contacts"];
    [rel addObject:newContact];

    contact.parseID = newContact.objectId;
}];
```

I've also checked if the `PFObject trip` is correct and I get back the desired object with the corresponding id. Also the key `contacts` is double-checked and correct.

Comment: You never save the relation... Your code's kind of reversed in a sense... I'll type up an answer to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you never save the relation. You create the `PFRelation` within the block, add an object to it, and do nothing else with it... You never save it.

Instead, try fetching the `trip` object and creating the `PFRelation` *outside* of the save block, ex:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Trip"];
PFObject *trip = [query getObjectWithId:self.parseID];

PFObject *newContact = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Contact"];

PFRelation *rel = [trip relationForKey:@"contacts"];
[rel addObject:newContact];

[newContact saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    contact.parseID = newContact.objectId;
}];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out my dumb mistake! I've just added the line `[trip saveInBackground]` inside the block, so I do not have to do the query for `trip` synchronous.